# WebView, проигрываем видео с sd карты

Tags: android

Пытаюсь проиграть видео в WebView с sd карты:

```
  WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);

    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    String videoPath="file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/AnySign/tt.mp4";
    String html =   "<html>" +
                        "<head>" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                            "<video width=\"365\" height=\"200\" src=\""+videoPath+"\" controls autobuffer>" +
                            "</video>" +
                        "</body>" +
                    "</html>";
    browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

но видео не проигрываеться.... В чем могут быть проблемы? Если попытаться обратиться к картинке таким же способом(но заменить тег video на img), то картинка показываться без проблем.

Comment: videoPath как получаете?

Comment: в приведенном примере я просто закинул файл tt.mp4 в папку AnySign, данный путь работает если тудаже кидать тикстуру